# Optimizing nested queries (particularly GROUP BY) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by

**The table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `temperature` (
   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `hive_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `value` decimal(4,1) NOT NULL,
   `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
   `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `idplusdate` (`hive_id`,`created_at`),
   KEY `hive_id` (`hive_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=360001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**The query:**

```
SELECT 
            hives.guid as hive_guid,

            temperature.id as Temperature_id,
            temperature.hive_id as Temperature_hive_id,
            temperature.value as Temperature_value,
            temperature.created_at as Temperature_created_at,
            temperature.updated_at as Temperature_updated_at

FROM hives

INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                *,
                @num := if(@hive_id = hive_id, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
                @hive_id := hive_id as dummy
             FROM
                  (SELECT * 
                  FROM temperature FORCE INDEX (idplusdate)
                  ORDER BY hive_id, created_at desc) T
             GROUP BY hive_id, created_at 
             HAVING row_number <= 2
          ) temperature
ON hives.id = temperature.hive_id

WHERE hives.guid IN ('tfdb3560-200a-45f7-ab0e-d699fty8w9b9');
```

**Explain:**

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY hives   ref PRIMARY,hives_guid_index    hives_guid_index    110 const   1   Using where; Using index
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 4   XXX.hives.id    359 NULL
2   DERIVED <derived3>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    359640  Using temporary; Using filesort
3   DERIVED temperature ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    359640  Using filesort
```

Ok, so I have a table `hives` with items with GUIDs (not very important to this query). I also have a `temperature` table, which contains multiple sensor readings from each hive. The goal of the query is to get the last N (in this case 2) sensor readings for a particular GUID (bear in mind this query will be used with multiple GUIDs, that's why I'm using the WHERE IN). I know the query is a bit complex for such a mundane task, but that's the best I found for large data sets (if you have any suggestions, please share)

**The expected result in this case is:**

```
tfdb8560-200a-45f7-ab0e-d699fty8w9b9    2879    8   29.6    9/28/2014 12:00 9/28/2014 12:00
tfdb3560-200a-45f7-ab0e-d699fty8w9b9    2880    8   26.6    9/28/2014 18:00 9/28/2014 18:00
```

As the table has many rows (360k in this case, expected to be in the millions) the query takes 3-4secs to execute. I'm looking to lower this time and I identified the GROUP BY as the main culprit for the lengthy times (as it obviously doesn't have any index to group by).

So I would take any approaches to improving query time, as long as the end result is the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is overly complicated.  If I understand it correctly, you don't need the `group by` at all.  Here is an alternate version of the `FROM` clause:

```
FROM hives INNER JOIN
     (SELECT t.*,
             (@num := if(@hive_id = hive_id, @num + 1,
                         if(@hive_id := hive_id, 1, 1)
             ) as row_number
      FROM temperature t CROSS JOIN
           (select @num := 0, @hive_id := '') vars
      ORDER BY hive_id, created_at desc
     ) temperature
     ON hives.id = temperature.hive_id and temperature.row_number <= 2;
```

Note that I put all the variable assignments into a single expression.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.  Your original version depended on `row_number` being evaluated before `dummy`.

Comment: Outstanding, thank you so much. A bit off-topic - can you suggest a book (or other type of source) for mastering such intermediate/advanced queries?